# How can I fill gradually an array in a loop without declaring it as ones or zeros/empty in Python?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to fill an array gradually in a loop and display the result by every iteration, so that I don’t like to declare it as ones or zeros. Is there any technique to achieve that? 
Here is an example in which I want to fill xp and yp gradually. Defining xp and yp as empty falsifies the plots! Any help please?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

a=.1
dt=.05

nx=33
ny=33

px=1
py=1

qx=1.0*px/(nx-1)
qy=1.0*py/(ny-1)

x = np.linspace(0,px,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,py,ny)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, px), ylim=(0, py))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

ax.set_xlim(0,px)
ax.set_ylim(0,py)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

U=-a*Y
V=a*X

x1=.5
y1=.5

xp=np.empty(nx)
yp=np.empty(ny)

xp[0]=x1
yp[0]=y1

def animate(i):
    xp[i+1]=xp[i]+dt*U[yp[i]/qy,xp[i]/qx]
    yp[i+1]=yp[i]+dt*V[yp[i]/qy,xp[i]/qx]
    line.set_data(xp,yp)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
       frames=int(10), interval=5, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: M4 I have just rectify the program. My current problem is how to fill an array gradually without declaring it as ones or zeros/empty. Could you help me please? Thank you!

Comment: a numpy array have to have some kind of data defined (1\0\empty). Use a python list and append every new value to it instead.

Comment: Thank you @M4rtini for your help. I have just a similar question in stackoverflow. I answered to my own question! Thank you again M4!

Answer (score 0):

In order to declare an array without filling it with ones or zeros/empty you may use for your 2 vectors the following:

```
xp = [None] * 80
yp = [None] * 80
```

And all now is going well!